# SPAN traffic for "Internet to Ext FW"

Tags: firewalls, monitoring

Is it advisable to mirror the traffic between the internet and the external firewall while the management interface is accessible from within the network? This is to perform packet capture and security analysis.
The box has 2 NICs. One is for packet capture which where the traffic is mirrored and sent to the box. The other interface is the management interface in the internal network.

Since the traffic going back and forth between the "Internet and External firewall" is being captured by the box which is also accessible in the internal network (in a way bypassing all firewalls and controls), can the box be compromised and then get into the internal network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally not advisable.  To prevent possible bypassing of the firewall, consider adding a management zone/DMZ where the management interface would be connected. Traffic would have to pass through a firewall from the internal network to access the management interface and deny any traffic initiated from the management zone/DMZ to the internal network.

Bonus: If you have many zones of varying security levels, dedicate a firewall to the management zones/DMZs.